# Python equivalent for Matlab's fmincon for constrained nonlinear optimization

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, scientific-computing

I'm currently trying to implement a Python script for solving a constrained nonlinear optimization problem with ~1000 variables and ~700 constraints (both linear and nonlinear). There already exists a Matlab implementation of this script, so I'm essentially just trying to find a Python solver that has equivalent performance to Matlab's `fmincon()`.

The Matlab code has analytic solutions for both the objective and constraint hessian and jacobian, which I've rewritten entirely in Python. I've verified that the Python code is correct by calling the Python hessian/jacobian function from `fmincon()` and making sure that the same solution is reached. For reference, the Matlab code passes the following options to `fmincon()`:

```
fmincon options:

   Options used by current Algorithm ('interior-point'):
   (Other available algorithms: 'active-set', 'sqp', 'sqp-legacy', 'trust-region-reflective')

   Set properties:
                    Algorithm: 'interior-point'
               CheckGradients: 0
                      Display: 'none'
         HessianApproximation: 'on'
                   HessianFcn: @(x,lambda)hessian(x,lambda,bCells,d0,rBX,rBY,mask)
       MaxFunctionEvaluations: 1000000
                MaxIterations: 2000
          OptimalityTolerance: 1.0000e-06
    SpecifyConstraintGradient: 1
     SpecifyObjectiveGradient: 1

   Default properties:
           BarrierParamUpdate: 'monotone'
          ConstraintTolerance: 1.0000e-06
     FiniteDifferenceStepSize: 'sqrt(eps)'
         FiniteDifferenceType: 'forward'
           HessianMultiplyFcn: []
                  HonorBounds: 1
               ObjectiveLimit: -1.0000e+20
                    OutputFcn: []
                      PlotFcn: []
                 ScaleProblem: 0
                StepTolerance: 1.0000e-10
          SubproblemAlgorithm: 'factorization'
                     TypicalX: 'ones(numberOfVariables,1)'
                  UseParallel: 0
```

So far I've attempted to use `trust-constr` algorithm in `scipy.optimize.minimize` and `cyipopt` but neither of these have worked. `trust-constr` doesn't perform as well and in particular might be struggling with parameter scaling (variables with smaller values are far away from the optimal value), while `cyipopt` doesn't converge at all. Both of these optimizers are also much slower than `fmincon()`. Are there any other Python packages that come close to the performance of `fmincon()`?

Comment: Can you provide your Python and Matlab codes? Otherwise, it is a bit difficult to help reasonably, as my first advice would also have been to use `trust-constr` or cyipopt.

Comment: @joni a complete minimal reproducible example might be difficult since the code comes at the end of a pipeline and there's a lot of additional parameters and input data required. As an example the Matlab code is available [here](https://github.com/nnoll/tissueAnalysisSuite/blob/master/%2BfitDual/%2BAFN/returnDual.m). I'm currently looking for more general help on whether `cyipopt` and `trust-constr` can achieve similar performance to `fmincon` or if I should try another package entirely.

Comment: @joni In particular I'm wondering about the relative performance of `cyipopt` and `trust-constr`; my `cyipopt` implementation is unable to reduce the objective function at all despite using the same code as the `trust-constr` implementation, so I'm not sure if that's to be expected or if I made a mistake in the code.

Comment: In my experience, the Ipopt solver should be at least on par with Matlab's fmincon. So your observation that cyipopt is much slower indicates that there's something going wrong in your python code. Have you provided all exact derivatives, i.e. the gradient, jacobian and hessian? Have you tried different starting points? Is your problem convex?

Comment: I've provided exact derivatives, but there does seem to be a problem with the hessian. Using the derivative checker, I'm getting a constant 3.333e-01 relative error on the objective hessian as well as errors on the constraint hessians. This is somewhat confusing as I'm not sure where `cyipopt` is getting the constraint and objective hessians from, since I'm only providing the hessian of the lagrangian.

Comment: I'll ask this as a separate question though since it's strayed a bit from the point of the original question

Answer (score 1):

There are several [high-quality nonlinear programming solvers in Python](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/83/is-there-a-high-quality-nonlinear-programming-solver-for-python). From the comments, it sounds like one of the issues is that the Hessian or Jacobian is not correct in cyipopt. One alternative is to try using a modeling platform such as `pyomo` or `gekko` to provide the derivatives. Here is a comparison of `fmincon` and `gekko` on the same problem (Hock Schittkowski #71).

[image: Optimization problem]

**Matlab fmincon**

```matlab
% create file nlcon.m for nonlinear constraints
function [c,ceq] = nlcon(x)
  c = 25.0 - x(1)*x(2)*x(3)*x(4);
  ceq = sum(x.^2) - 40;
```

```matlab
objective = @(x) x(1)*x(4)*(x(1)+x(2)+x(3))+x(3);

% initial guess
x0 = [1,5,5,1];

% variable bounds
lb = 1.0 * ones(4);
ub = 5.0 * ones(4);

% linear constraints
A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];

% nonlinear constraints
nonlincon = @nlcon;

% optimize with fmincon
%[X,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,LAMBDA,GRAD,HESSIAN] 
% = fmincon(FUN,X0,A,B,Aeq,Beq,LB,UB,NONLCON,OPTIONS)
x = fmincon(objective,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlincon);

% show final objective
disp(['Final Objective: ' num2str(objective(x))])

% print solution
disp('Solution')
disp(['x1 = ' num2str(x(1))])
disp(['x2 = ' num2str(x(2))])
disp(['x3 = ' num2str(x(3))])
disp(['x4 = ' num2str(x(4))])
```

**Python gekko**

Call gekko from MATLAB:

```matlab
clear all
% Initialize model
m = py.gekko.GEKKO();
% Initialize Variables
x1 = m.Var(pyargs('value',1,'lb',1,'ub',5));
x2 = m.Var(pyargs('value',5,'lb',1,'ub',5));
x3 = m.Var(pyargs('value',5,'lb',1,'ub',5));
x4 = m.Var(pyargs('value',1,'lb',1,'ub',5));
% Define Equations
m.Equation(x1*x2*x3*x4>=25);
m.Equation(x1^2+x2^2+x3^2+x4^2==40);
% Objective
m.Obj(x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3)
% Solve
m.solve();
% Extract values from Python lists using curly brackets
disp(['x1: ' num2str(x1.VALUE{1})]);
disp(['x2: ' num2str(x2.VALUE{1})]);
disp(['x3: ' num2str(x3.VALUE{1})]);
disp(['x4: ' num2str(x4.VALUE{1})]);
```

Solve optimization problem directly in Python (not MATLAB) with gekko:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO    
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Array(m.Var,4,value=1,lb=1,ub=5)
x1,x2,x3,x4 = x
# change initial values
x2.value = 5; x3.value = 5
m.Equation(x1*x2*x3*x4>=25)
m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2+x4**2==40)
m.Minimize(x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3)
m.solve()
print('x: ', x)
print('Objective: ',m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```

The modeling language compiles the model into byte-code that includes automatic differentiation for the 1st and 2nd derivatives. It is as fast as if were written in C or Fortran once the model is compiled. Problems with 1000 variables and 700 constraints typically solve in a couple seconds, depending on the degree of nonlinearity.